# Exception Handling in Azure Mobile App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Mobile App Service and hosted that on Azure.
Sometime specific line of code throws exception and I'm not handling those. Instead I'm logging those in ExceptionFilterAttribute.

The problem I'm facing is, those exceptions are reported as unhandled by Azure App Service which I think is true. My question is, how can I improve the below line of code such that it will not be considered unhandled exception?

```
public async Task<SingleResult<DTO.Responses.User>> GetUser(string id, OS os = OS.iOS, string openUrl = null)
{
    /* some code written here that sometimes throws exception */            
}
```

if I add try...catch block how will this be handled by Mobile App sync framework?

Below is code for exception filter

```
public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{        
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        /* Log exception here*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, we could use [global error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) handing.

We could get the following demo code from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21).

```
public class TraceSourceExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    private readonly TraceSource _traceSource;

    public TraceSourceExceptionLogger(TraceSource traceSource)
    {
        _traceSource = traceSource;
    }

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1,
            "Unhandled exception processing {0} for {1}: {2}",
            context.Request.Method,
            context.Request.RequestUri,
            context.Exception);
    }
}

config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), 
    new TraceSourceExceptionLogger(new 
    TraceSource("MyTraceSource", SourceLevels.All)));
```

Then we could config it in the ConfigureMobileApp method

```
Public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
{
     HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
     config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger),
    new TraceSourceExceptionLogger(new
    TraceSource("MyTraceSource", SourceLevels.All)));
            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);
         ...
   app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```